# How to workaround 'unsafe repository' in git without modifying config?

Tags: git

I have a situation where I need to have a daemonized process do a git head of its own checked out repo to report its current sha1.  I don't want to run the daemonized process as the owner of the files and I don't want to modify the daemon's global git config.

How can avoid this error?

```
fatal: unsafe repository ('/opt/project' is owned by someone else)
To add an exception for this directory, call:

        git config --global --add safe.directory /opt/project
```

Answer (score 0):

This limit is due to [CVE-2022-24765](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/cve-2022-24765) where git might look at parent directories to find a git repo, which can cause arbitrary code to be executed in the user's shell.

It looks like a way to circumvent this check is to explicitly set `GIT_DIR` to /opt/project/.git in the shell environment.

```
sudo env GIT_DIR=/opt/project/.git git log
```